# Stop JavaScript function after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

Heyo,

I want to call a function that disables the scrollwheel while the Preloader is shown. But after the Preloader is gone, the scrollwhell should be usable again.
I got the function which disables the scrollwheel allready. Now I need a simple code which makes it run only the first 3 seconds.

My anitscrollwheel function looks like so: `window.onwheel = function(){ return false; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var wheelEnabled = false;

    window.onwheel = function() { return wheelEnabled; }

    setTimeout(function() {
        wheelEnabled = true;
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Exacly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
var enable_scroll = false;

//When preloader ends, set enable_scroll = true;

window.onwheel = function(){
    if(enable_scroll == false) {
        return false; 
    }
}
```